# C++ compilation error, ambigous operator overloads

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, ambiguous

I have a template array class overloading both `operator []` to access items and `operator T *` to get direct buffer access.

```
template< typename T > class buffer
{
    const T & operator [] ( size_t ) const;
          T & operator [] ( size_t );

    operator const T * () const;
    operator       T * ();
};
```

For some reason, using `operator []` on an instance of this class generates a compilation error saying that there is 4 possible overloads.

```
buffer< int > buf;
buf[ some_position ] = 0; // Generates an error
```

Error :

```
Error   3   error C2666: 'XXX::buffer<T>::operator []' : 4 overloads have similar conversions   c:\XXX.cpp  3886
```

Is the `operator []` trying to convert my instance `buf` to a `T *` ? Why are 4 overloads detected instead of 2 ? Thank you. :)

EDIT :
Actually it is : `buf[ some_position ] = 0; // Generates an error`

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message, including all the overloads it lists and any other related notes generated by compiler.

Comment: This is the full error message. I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: It explains [here](https://ideone.com/bel9Rm) why you are getting your errors.  Look in the compilation info section at the bottom.

Comment: @Virus721, hm, ok, that old VS might not give much additional info...

Comment: What is the type of `some_position`? A literal `int`? An `int` variable? A `std::size_t` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have implicit conversions going in both directions.

Disregarding `const`, your two candidates are:

```
T & buffer::operator [] ( size_t );
int& operator[] (int*, int);
```

For the call `buf[pos]` where `pos` is an `int` (such as a literal), the call is ambiguous. The first candidate could be selected by converting `pos` to a `std::size_t` and the second could be selected by converting `buf` to `int*`.

You could disambiguate this call by explicitly casting the argument to a `std::size_t`, or modifying the operator to take an `int` instead.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about `int& operator[] (int*, int);` I guess it is a non-member operator casting the object using its `operator T *` ?

Comment: It's just the built-in operation for indexing an integer pointer as an array. The compiler checks that because of your implicit conversion operator to `T*`.

Comment: I assume that i should avoid coupling these two overloads and use a named method to access the buffer instead, shouldn't it ? Like std::vector

Comment: That's certainly a good option if it fits with your use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem you are having is that `operator T*` and `operator[]` both will allow `buf[some_position]` to be valid.  In your code `T*` is an `int*` and `int*` has an `[]` overload.

You can see that with this [live example](https://ideone.com/bel9Rm)

I think this might be an issue with you VS as running the code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c938150606e84349) and [ideone](https://ideone.com/m9G3NN) with some modifications to get it to run both give working code.

Comment: Btw, g++ lists only 2 candidates, and OP's compiler (VS2005) says four. Is it just that OP has outdated Visual Studio?

Comment: Yeah I am going to code with a VS problem.  [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c938150606e84349) doesn't mind it.

Comment: That's only part of the issue, as there needs to be ambiguous implicit conversions for the call to be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question, i forgot the assignment, so it wasn't about a const / not-const, but what TartanLlama said.